# Hide the ID in the URL

Tags: grails

In Grails the URL like this

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/show/2
```

is there a way to hide or to encrypt the **id** part

```
/2
```

i need to do this to prevent users to access others data , for instance my ID is 3 , i could access other user's data by typing

```
/show/4
```

Comment: why you need this? can you provide more details? because it seems that such question could have many possible answers, and none of them will be right

Comment: ok, I see. then encoding, hiding, POST or anything like this will not help. you need security plugin, see spring-security-core plugin

Comment: @IgorArtamonov i tired the **Spring security plugin** , but i found that anyone got the the specified role on the action **@Secure('ROLE_UESR')** can access others data for the same action.

Comment: you need to check actual user or use ACL

Comment: @IgorArtamonov is right you should consider using a security plugin. Since just hiding the url will not protect the data it will only hide the underlying problem.

Comment: Is there any available tutorials or examples for using spring ACL ?

Answer (score 0):

You can encode the url. If you replace the 2 with `%32`, the browser will still interpret it as the character 2. Here is a [complete list](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) of characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can send [POST](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Controllers/allowedMethods.html) request instead of GET - this is an easy way of hiding such a request parameters f.e. in server log files.

Or you can play with GRAILS [codecs](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.5/ref/Plug-ins/codecs.html).

Comment: i made as you suggested  `static allowedMethods = [index:['POST', 'GET'],show:'POST']` to send all by POST method but nothing changed

Comment: Please check out these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384931/how-to-only-accept-post-variables-in-grails

Answer (score 0):

I would not hide the ID from the url. Why? because this would only mask the problem.

Consider having a class defined as :

```
class Post {

String  title
String content
User   user //you need this to keep track of the posts owner
//You could use your own custom class or the one used in spring security

...
}
```

If you use **Spring Security Core**, you would use a fucntion similar to:

```
def springSecurityService


@Secured(['ROLE_USER'])
def myFunction(Long id){
   def postInstance = Post.read(id)

  if(postInstance){
   if (postInstance.user.id ==(long)springSecurityService.principal.id){
     // springSecurityService?.principal?.id retrieves the id of the user in session 
     //... redirect to details of whatever you need
   }else{

     //... redirect because it is not the owner of the post

   }

 } 

else{

  //... Redirect or something
    }  

}
```

If you are using a simple session you would need to have a function like

```
def myFunction(Long id){
   def postInstance = Post.read(id)
   long userId = session["user_id"]

  if(postInstance && userId > 0){
   if (postInstance.user.id ==userId){
     //... redirect to details of whatever you need
   }else{

     //... redirect because it is not the owner of the post

   }

 } 

else{

  //... Redirect or something
    }  

}
```

The logic is very similar. Still in my humble opinion you should use the spring Security plugin.