# HttpServletRequest getParameterMap - Fetch the form parameters alone

Tags: java, filter, jax-rs

`getParameterMap()` of HttpServletRequest returns both the query params and posted form data.

I am able to fetch the query parameters alone from `UriInfo.getQueryParameters()`.

But I need the form parameters separately as a `MultivaluedMap` similar to query parameters, is there a way to fetch it?

### EDITED:

I apologize for not making this clear. I am trying to fetch the form parameters in the filter/interceptor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieve POST parameters only (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197729/retrieve-post-parameters-only-java)

Comment: You can't do this without some manual work, unfortunately.

Comment: What JAX-RS implementation are you using?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha I am using Jersey

Comment: Check out my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the `MultivaluedMap` as a parameter in the resource method. This will be the body of the request. JAX-RS will put all the parameters in the map for you.

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public Response post(@Context UriInfo uriInfo, MultivaluedMap params) {}
```

### UPDATE (to edited post)

So if you want to get the parameters in a filter, you can get the body from the `ContainerRequestContext`. With Jersey, instead of getting the `InputStream` with `context.getEntityStream()`, you can cast the `ContainerRequestContext` to Jersey's `ContainerRequest` implementation. This will give you access to the methods `bufferEntity()` and `readEntity()`. These methods will allow you do easily get the form parameters. You will need to buffer the entity so that it can be read later when it needs to be passed on to your resource method.

```
@Provider
public class MyFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext context) throws IOException {
        if (MediaTypes.typeEqual(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE, context.getMediaType())) { {
            return;
        }
        ContainerRequest request = (ContainerRequest) context;
        request.bufferEntity();
        Form form = request.readEntity(Form.class);
        MultivaluedMap params<String, String> = form.asMap();
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> query = context.getUriInfo().getQueryParameters();
    }
}
```

If you want to use the filter only with specific resource methods, then you can use [Name Binding](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9678) or [Dynamic Binding](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9751).

If for some reason the `readEntity()` returns an empty map (I've seen rare occurrences of people having this problem), you can try to retrieve the `Form` through an internal property

```
Object formProperty = request.getProperty(InternalServerProperties.FORM_DECODED_PROPERTY);
if (formProperty != null) {
    Form for = (Form) formProperty;
}
```